# GGplot Custom Y-Axis Tick Labels (Numeric Data)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting race time data with seconds on the Y-Axis and Date on the X-Axis. However, I would like to convert the Y-Axis labels to minute:seconds format without changing the numeric nature of the data. I used the following code to create my ggplot:

```
plotab2 = ggplot(AB1000, aes(Date, secs)) + 
  geom_point(size=3, colour= "darkred" ) +
  geom_line(size=0.5, colour = "darkred") +
  ylim(77,87) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = hline1000 ,size =0.4,linetype="dashed", colour="darkblue") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Time (s)", title="1000m") +
  Presentation_Theme
```

And attempted to edit the Y-Axis labels with the following:

```
plotab2 + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(77.5,80.0,82.5,85.0,87.5),
                             labels=c("1:17.5", "1:20.00", "1:22.50", "1:25.00", "1:27.5"))
```

Curiously, the resulting plot did work (sort of), and returned only the 1:20.00 label. Hoping for some help in getting the other values to show

[image: Here is the resulting plot for reference]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: We need to see some or all of the data in `AB1000`, in plain text format. The best way is to use `dput(AB1000)` (if not too large), as then we can see the variable type for the x and y variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using some arbitrary data here that mimics your `AB1000`. Your code already does everything you want, if you just replace `ylim(77,87)` with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(77, 87))`. (Otherwise you try to specify the y scale twice, as indicated by the warning `Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.` - which simply removes the limits you initially set to the axis).

If you want more automatic date labelling, you can also check the `scales` package, which allows to specify the ticks a la `scale_y_time(breaks=date_breaks("2 sec"))`

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame("Date" = as.Date(c("2021-09-01", "2021-09-18", "2021-10-11", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-12", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-07")),
                 "secs" = c(78.5, 81, 87, 79, 81, 82, 77.2))
hline1000 <- 78

ggplot(df, aes(Date, secs)) + 
  geom_point(size=3, colour= "darkred" ) +
  geom_line(size=0.5, colour = "darkred") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(77, 87)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = hline1000 ,size =0.4,linetype="dashed", colour="darkblue") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Time (s)", title="1000m") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(77.5,80.0,82.5,85.0,87.5),
                     labels=c("1:17.5", "1:20.00", "1:22.50", "1:25.00", "1:27.5")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Very kind of you to generate example data. In general I think it's better to wait and see if there's a response to the requests asking for improvements to the question.

Comment: Fair point, that probably makes more sense.